# Where can I find the error log for Neo4j 3.0.0 server

Tags: java, neo4j, jetty

I am currently building an unmanaged extension for Neo4j 3.0.0. After placing the extension jar file into the plugins folder, I restart the Neo4j server. Some requests work but others don't. The server prompts a `HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error` reply without any further details.

Where can I find the log file that contains all the jetty/java errors?

I looked into: `messages.log`, `logs/debug.log` and `logs/http.log` without any luck.

Comment: logs/neo4j.log perhaps?

Comment: You deserve a medal. The file resides in `/Library` directory on OSX, which is not where I was looking in. Thanks again. You can answer the question.

Comment: @wael34218 Could you mark the answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [current documentation (3.1), file locations](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.1/configuration/file-locations/)

The location depends on which system you have installed Neo4J.

```
Linux or OS X tarball   <neo4j-home>/logs
Windows zip             <neo4j-home>\logs
Debian/Ubuntu .deb      /var/log/neo4j
Windows desktop         %APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\logs
OS X desktop            ${HOME}/Documents/Neo4j/logs
```

Answer (score 1):

On linux it is in `/var/log/neo4j/`

Comment: which flavour? all?